# Nginx config: how to use auth_basic authentication if ssl_client_certificate none provided?

Tags: authentication, drupal, nginx, config

I'm trying to set up Nginx server as follows:

First, the server should check whether the user provides the client SSL certificate (via **ssl_client_certificate**).
If the SSL certificate is provided, then give access to the site,

If the SSL certificate is NOT provided, then ask the user to enter a password and logs through **auth_basic**.

I was able to configure both the authentication method *at the same time*. But this config is superfluous.

To make check, whether the user provides its SSL certificate I try the config like this:

```
18:    if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
19:        auth_basic "Please login";
20:        auth_basic_user_file .passfile;
21:    }
```

But Nginx returns an error:

> "auth_basic" directive is not allowed here in .../ssl.conf:19

How can I to set the condition in this case?

Comment: hi pavel, did you ever manage to do whta you wanted? i have quite the same problem...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can set `auth_basic` configuration in the `if` clause like this:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    auth_basic_user_file    .htpasswd;
    ssl_client_certificate  ca.cert;
    ssl_verify_client       optional;
    ...

    location / {
      ...

      if ($ssl_client_verify = SUCCESS) {
        set $auth_basic off;
      }
      if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
        set $auth_basic Restricted;
      }

      auth_basic $auth_basic;
    }
}
```

Now, authentication falls back to HTTP Basic if no client certificate has been provided (or if validation failed).

Comment: Simplify: set $auth_basic Restricted; if ($ssl_client_verify = SUCCESS) {set $auth_basic off;}

Answer (score 4):

I'm unable to test this currently, but would something like this work?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
server {
    listen 443;
    ...

    if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
        rewrite ^ http://auth.example.com/ permanent;
    } 
    location / {
        ...
    }

}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name auth.example.com;
    location / {
        auth_basic "Please login";
        auth_basic_user_file .passfile;
    }
}
```

So basically:
- Accept all initial request (on port 80 for whatever name you're using) and rewrite to ssl
- Check if there's an the client is verified.
- If not, rewrite to an alternate domain that uses basic auth

Like I said, I can't test it right now, but I'll try to get around to it! Let me know if it helps, I'm interested to see if it works.

Comment: Curious about this, did you ever get it working? Did the above implementation work?

Answer (score 4):

You may try using a map.

```
map $ssl_client_verify $var_auth_basic {
   default off;
   SUCCESS "Please login";
}

server {
   ....
   auth_basic $var_auth_basic;
   auth_basic_user_file .passfile;
```

that way the value depends on `$ssl_client_verify` but is alsa always defined and `auth_basic` and `auth_basic_user_file` is always inside `server {` block.

Answer (score 3):

Nginx provides no way to fall back to basic authentication when client cert fails. As an alternative you can use variables to restrict access:

```
location / { 
  if ($ssl_client_verify = "SUCCESS") {
    set $authorized 1;
  }
  if ($authorized != 1) {
    error_page 401 @basicauth;
    return 401;
  }
}

location @basicauth {
  auth_basic "Please login";
  auth_basic_user_file .passfile;
  set $authorized 1;
  rewrite /(.*) /$1;
}
```

*keep in mind that [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) and these rules may work incorrectly or interfere with other parts of a larger configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about it, **it won't work.**

The reason why it fails is because `if` is not part of the general configuration module as one should believe. `if` is part of the rewrite module and `auth_basic` is another module. You just cannot have dynamic vhosts with basic auth.

### On the other hand...

You can have dynamic vhosts with their own error pages. The following example is designed for a custom 404 page but you can implement it into your code.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    set $site_root /data/www/$host;

    location / {
        root $site_root;
    }

    error_page 404 =404 /404.html;

    location /404.html {
        root $site_root/error_files;
        internal;

        error_page 404 =404 @fallback_404;
    }

    location @fallback_404 {
        root /var/www/;
        try_files /404.html =404;
        internal;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

### What happens...

- you are telling Nginx to use `/404.html` in case of `HTTP_NOT_FOUND`.
- changing the location `root` to match the Web site `error_pages` directory.
- internal redirection
- returning a 404 http code
- configure the fallback 404 page in `location @fallback_404`: In this location, the `root` is changed to `/var/www/` so it will read files from that path instead of `$site_root`
- at the last stage the code returns `/var/www/404.html` if it exists with a 404 http code.

*NOTE: According to Nginx documentation :*

> Specifies that a given location can only be used for internal
>   requests. For external  requests, the client error 404 (Not Found) is
>   returned. Internal requests are the  following:
>
> - requests redirected by the error_page, index, random_index, and    try_files directives;
> - requests redirected by the “X-Accel-Redirect” response header field    from an upstream server;
> - subrequests formed by the “include virtual” command of the    ngx_http_ssi_module module and by the ngx_http_addition_module module 
>     directives;
> - requests changed by the rewrite directive.

Also:

> There is a limit of 10 internal redirects per request to prevent
>   request processing cycles that can occur in incorrect configurations.
>   If this limit is reached, the error 500 (Internal Server Error) is
>   returned. In such cases, the “rewrite or internal redirection cycle”
>   message can be seen in the error log.

Check [this link](https://t37.net/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-of-virtual-hosting-with-nginx.html) for more, hope that helps.